# Getting "Cannot read property 'left' of undefined" of .position().left while html is created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating some HTML elements dynamically on ready based on sort some data retrieved from an ajax and adding them into a `<div id='wrapper'>`.
For example below code

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    <ul class='nav nav-tabs list'>
        <li class="box"><a class='filter-select'>Brokers</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And there is a code piece looks like below

```
var getLeftPosi = function () {
    var left = $('.list').position().left + 11.5;
    return left;
};
```

Now my problem is that if I create my HTML dynamically then `.position().left` in the above js issues `Cannot read property 'left' of undefined`. But if I hard code the HTML then it works. What I probably doing wrong

Comment: It means that the element doesn't exist by the time `getLeftPosi()` is called. You'll have to show how you create the HTML and when you call the function. The most likely problem is that you do the Ajax call and don't wait for it to finish.

Comment: how you are creating your dynamic elements? I mean show us the code.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is element you add by javascript or jquery is not exists in DOM tree.

So `$('.list')` is `undefined` because `class="list"` don't exists

To fix it, you must "reload" `DOM tree`

Reference : https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/